# Anylogic 3D models naming issue

Tags: linux, anylogic

I'm using anylogic 8.5.1 and 8.5.2 in ubuntu 18.04.

When I add 3d models I get the `error unable to copy file model folder: /machine.dae`. The file is actually named `Machine.dae`, so it is clearly a case of upper and lower case.

If I manually rename the files in `anylogic/plugins` it works but this is getting annoying. Is there any quick workarounds (find all .dae files in subfolder and rename uppercase starters as lower) and are there channels to report this to the developers?

Comment: You can report it to the devs using support@anylogic.com, can't help further though. Never had issues on Windows

Comment: Support responded and are looking into it. Thanks.